# how to disable native android apps

Tags: android

I want to disable or uninstall or remove all the native android apps from my Tablet.I want only my application to run on the tablet,so that the end user is able to connect to the internet or browse.My application connects to the internet automatically after an interval of time and does the needful.

**In short i want to customize the the Android 2.3.3 in my tablet so that there is no other application in the tablet except my custom application.**

As soon as the end user switches on the tablet, i want my application to start.All you can do is play with my application or do nothing ;)

Comment: To uninstall the base android apps, you'll need to root the device.  Then, connect to it with ADB, remount the system partition in read-write mode, and start deleting the apps you don't want from `/system/app` directory.  Be very careful though: some of the system-required app (i.e. parts of the operating system itself) are there as well and if you delete them, you'll render the whole tablet useless.  To get your app to auto-start on boot, have a look at this link: http://www.androidsnippets.com/autostart-an-application-at-bootup

Comment: the tablet i am using is a very cheap one..its giving me real hard time..my laptop does not even recognize the tablet when i connect it via USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to create a custom build of Android using your device after you root it and uninstall all apps but yours then this may help: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=633246

if you are well-experienced then it is better to work on the source code of the Android OS directly, you can find it here: http://source.android.com/source/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You could register your app as a custom launcher. This App would appear after booting the devices and whenever the user hits the home button.

You can do this with a special intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```